# Checkbox in Internet Explorer 11 using strange font instead of a check mark

Tags: internet-explorer, fonts

When I open Internet Explorer 11, the check box is using some "hand with a pencil" sign from Webdings instead of a check mark.

[image]

I guess, I did something with the system fonts or the custom font settings. How do I fix it?

Comment: Normally, "Marlett" was used back in the Classic theme, maybe this font is gone and substituted with Webdings?

Answer (score 1):

**Segoe UI Symbol** font was missing and after installing it the problem is resolved.